# DC/OS Mesos-Master rejoined and causes interruptions on the master agents

Tags: dcos

I'm having a strange issue today. First of all, every thing was still working fine yesterday when I left the office, but today when I went back to work my DC/OS dashboard showed my that there weren't any services running, or Nodes connected.

I've ran into this issue once or twice before and was related to the marathon not being able to elect a master. One of the 3 master nodes is then also showing a lot of errors in the journal. This can be resolved by stopping / starting the dcos-marathon service on that host, which brings it back into the marathon group.

I did see the Nodes and services again. But now it sometimes tells me there is only one Node connected and then 3 again, and just 1 again, etc..

When I stop the dcos-mesos-master process on the conflicting host, this stops and I have a stable master cluster (but probably not really resilient).

It looks like the failing node is trying to become the master, which causes this.. I've tried to search about rejoining a failed mesos-master.. but came up

I'm running DC/OS on a CoreOS environment.

Answer (score 0):

Although a general behavior is described, you may need to provide more specifics such as the kernel version, dc/os version, specs and etc.  The simplest answer I can provide based what's been given is to reach out via their support channel on Slack ( https://dcos-community.slack.com/ ).